# Detect the end of rotation in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I'm making some rotation for a wheel by using this transition:

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
transition: transform 10s cubic-bezier(.5,.1,.15,1);
```

Now, how can I detect the send of the transition with JS ?

Thanks.

Comment: are you expecting a callback in css?

Comment: Maybe you can add a listener to the [transitionend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event) and use some logic to discover that the event is related to the target of the transition. If you manage to generate a working example, we can help a little more.

Answer (score 0):

```
function whichTransitionEvent(){
var t,
  el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

var transitions = {
  "transition"      : "transitionend",
  "OTransition"     : "oTransitionEnd",
  "MozTransition"   : "transitionend",
  "WebkitTransition": "webkitTransitionEnd"
}


for (t in transitions){
  if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
    return transitions[t];
    }
 }
}

var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();


    $(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("animate");
   $(this).one(transitionEvent,
              function(event) {
    alert("The transition has ended!");
    $(this).removeClass("animate");
  });
});
```

solution using jquery
it can detect end of transition

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to detect the end of a transition:

The `off()` method can be used on the callback function to ensure that it will be fired only once.

```
$("#someSelector")
.on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd",
 function(e){
    // do something here
    $(this).off(e);
 });
```

If you are using pure js then you can use the following:

```
element.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", callfunction,false);
element.addEventListener("transitionend", callfunction,false);
element.addEventListener("oTransitionEnd", callfunction,false);
element.addEventListener("MSTransitionEnd", callfunction,false);
```

Further reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_start_and_completion_of_a_transition